# How to set Loading when the button is clicked and show the result after timeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please help. I can't make the loading appear correctly. So whenever the user click Login or Logout, it should be Loading... first for 2 second, and then show the result whether the user is Login or not. Instead, my current result is it always loading and never ends.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    user: "John Doe",
    isLogin: false,
    isLoading: false,
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState({
        isLoading: !state?.isLoading,
        user: state?.user,
        status: !state?.status,
        isLogin: !state?.isLogin,
      });
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Practice makes perfect</h1>
        {state?.isLoading ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>
            {state?.isLogin ? "Logout" : "Login"}
          </button>
        )}
        <p>{state?.isLogin ? `Hello ${state?.user}` : "Please Login"}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank you, sorry for bad english.

Comment: why you have empty `setState` over there? Also, you're abusing `useState`. Unlink `setState` in class components, `useState` should be used for a single state

Comment: Edited, already delete the empty setState. But I don't use class components, it's functional. Notice I didn't use class extends component something... Dunno, I just trying to use useState as an object. If you say it's a bad practice, I might stop this bad behaviour.

Comment: He's using the `useState` hook and is just happening to name its setter function `setState`.  It's not the class-based `setState`.  It's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this... your example is simple enough that you can do it this way and maybe you wouldn't want to do this in a "real" app, but first calling `setState` with your loading state, followed by an async call (here using `setTimeout`) to get your logged-in user info should work ok:

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    // Loading here while we wait for the setTimeout to kick off.
    setState({
      isLoading: true,
      user: undefined,
      status: "Loading",
      isLogin: false
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Assume success here
      setState({
        isLoading: false,
        user: "Logged-in Username",
        status: "success",
        isLogin: true
      });
    }, 2000);
  };
```

Here's a codesandbox where this is running.  https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-poincare-2jpio?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You need a handler to change your isLoading state when user clicked on the button. So this code is what you need:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    user: "John Doe",
    isLogin: false,
    isLoading: false,
  });

  const handleLoading = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState({
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isLogin: !state?.isLogin,
      });
    }, 2000);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState({
        ...state,
        isLoading: !state?.isLoading,
        user: state?.user,
        status: !state?.status,
        isLogin: !state?.isLogin,
      });
      handleLoading();
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
      <>
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Practice makes perfect</h1>
          {state?.isLoading ? (
              <p>Loading...</p>
          ) : (
              <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>
                {state?.isLogin ? "Logout" : "Login"}
              </button>
          )}
          <p>{state?.isLogin ? `Hello ${state?.user}` : "Please Login"}</p>
        </div>
      </>
  );
};

export default App;
```